# Adding watermark to a Access report page

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to add a watermark to an Access report using the "Picture" property and have run into an issue.  The following code works and the image is displayed/printed when the report is previewed and printed but does not work when the report is directly printed from a macro (nothing visible on-screen).  "GrandTotal" is a bound text box on the report that is the sum of a field in the record source.  I would appreciate any suggestion to print the watermark from both the print preview and the print macro.

```
Private Sub Report_Load
' put up the watermark if needed

    If GrandTotal.Value < 2000 Then
        Me.Picture = <<picture file name including full path>>
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the macro which is executing the report and how is it called?

Comment: It is a standard Access Macro with the following settings:  OpenReport, Report Name: DetailPrint, View: Print, Window Mode: Normal.  There is no Filter Name or Where Condition.  Printing without displaying the report is the desired action.

Comment: and you've put break points in the `Open` and `Load` events and they are not hit when you open the report with the macro?

Comment: I have and neither fires when the report is printed via the macro.  I also tried putting adding the line 'cTrash = InputBox("Firing", "Trash")' to the above code rather than using break points.  It also does not appear when the report is printed without previewing form the macro.  As a note, I was unable to use the Open for this when previewing and printing the report as the bound control had not been assigned a value.  That is why I was using the Load event.  One other note, if I change the view parameter of the OpenReport command to Report, the watermark appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are printing the report without it ever rendering to the screen the open/load events are never fired because they are never used. An alternative could be to open the report in print preview and use the `OpenArgs` to indicate you want to print it

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "DetailView", acViewPreview, , , acHidden, "Print"
End Sub
```

then do your normal loading stuff

```
Private Sub Report_Load
' put up the watermark if needed

    If GrandTotal.Value < 2000 Then
        Me.Picture = <<picture file name including full path>>
    End If
End Sub
```

and when the loading is done your form will Activate which is when you can print

```
Private Sub Report_Activate()
    If Me.OpenArgs = "Print" Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview
        'Opens print dialog for current screen (report in this case):
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
    End If
    DoCmd.Close
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 2501 Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The form is never shown so it looks like you had it set up before but the load/open events will fire like normal because the report is actually rendered.

Comment: Thank you @Brad - That is wonderful.  I will say the only thing I changed was  to replace acCmdPrint with acCmdQuickPrint in the sub Report_Activate().  This way, the report prints to the default printer without displaying the printer dialog box.