# Run Docmd.OpenReport with acNormal in which event to put code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

**The situation**

I have a report which is used for a receipt,
I made 2 buttons to extract it - one is to get a PDF and the other is to print. If using PDF then i need the background image. If printing then i don't (because it is being printed on pre-printed paper).
This is the code for PDF:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Receipt", acViewPreview, , "OrderID = " & Me.OrderID, acHidden, "PDF"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Receipt", acFormatPDF
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Receipt", acSaveN
```

This is the code for print:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Receipt", acViewNormal, , "OrderID = " & Me.OrderID, acHidden, "Prt"
```

I put the `openargs` so that i can set the `OnLoad` to hide the background when printing.

**The issue**

It seems that there is no `OnLoad` when opening the form with `acViewNormal` (used to auto print it)

**So**

Is there another way to program this or is there a way to make the background appear in print preview (for PDF) but not in actual print?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Make two report. One is with background image and other without image. Then code to print without image report and export pdf with image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding watermark to a Access report page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853386/adding-watermark-to-a-access-report-page)

Comment: I'd put it into the `Format` event of the appropriate report section.

Comment: @Andre That did it. Thanks. (If you suggest it as answer i can accept it.)

Comment: @June7 Technically it can work but i prefer do call the print as expected in `acNormal`

Comment: Are you not using the report Picture property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `On Format` event of the appropriate report section runs for both Print and Print Preview.

So this event is the best place to put this functionality into.